# Which RESTful framework will suit the Android and the Server-side as well?

Tags: java, android, restlet, rest-client, multiplatform

I'm trying to find a solution for a multiplatform REST Client (Android + Server-side + Desktop). I have a jar file with my DTO entities which used JAXB annotation.

The problem for now is that Android doesn't support JAXB (javax.xml.*). Furthermore I found that people usually replace their JAXB annotation with SimpleXML analog. But SimpleXML is a dead project (last update in 2012).

I made a research of frameworks which I can use as with Server-side as and with Android as well. And I found  two options:

- Spring RestTemplate
- Restlet

But both of them haven't any support of JAXB for Android. RestTemplate has a very limited set of features because it isn't JSR 311 implementation (my Web Service on Jersey use lots of features of JSR 311 such us Url matrix variables and many more).

Restlet for now is a raw project. It's complicated and too verbosity.

So maybe someone have another cool examples of frameworks which I can use with my issue. I need your advices.

Maybe there are some new cool RESTful frameworks, which I didn't notice yet.

Comment: What do you mean by Restlet being a "raw project"?